# Getting 'permission-denied' while integrating firebase in React web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save a documents through react web app, but facing the following issue. I have read the firebase rules documentation.

Here is the code

```
constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    var config = {
      apiKey: "<apiKey>",
      authDomain: "<authDomain>",
      databaseURL: "<databaseURL>",
      projectId: "<projectId>",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "<messagingSenderId>"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }
```

and we are triggering button click

```
onKeyUp(e)
    {
        if(e.keyCode===13 && trim(e.target.value) !== '')
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            let dbCon=this.props.db.database().ref('/messages');
            dbCon.push(
                {
                    message:trim(e.target.value)
                }
            );
            );
        }
    }
```

**`Database rules:`**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write:if true;
    }
  }
}
```

we are facing this issue. What am I doing wrong?

**`Stack Trace:`**

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
    at index.cjs.js:13076
    at exceptionGuard (index.cjs.js:690)
    at Repo../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Repo.callOnCompleteCallback (index.cjs.js:13067)
    at index.cjs.js:12844
    at index.cjs.js:12019
    at PersistentConnection../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (index.cjs.js:12052)
    at Connection../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Connection.onDataMessage_ (index.cjs.js:11337)
    at Connection../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (index.cjs.js:11331)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (index.cjs.js:11232)
    at WebSocketConnection../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (index.cjs.js:10837)
    at WebSocketConnection../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame (index.cjs.js:10887)
    at WebSocket.mySock.onmessage (index.cjs.js:10784)
```

Answer (score 1):

Newbie mistake, was using the newer firestore database instead of using the Realtime database. Changing to the Realtime database fixed the issue.

Comment: can you please elaborate. I think i have the same issue

Comment: Ya understood what you meant. But any idea why not to use the advanced version?? Why not Newer firestore database?

Comment: On the Database page, there will be a drop-down looking thing that says "Cloud Firestorm BETA". Click on that and change it to "Realtime Database".